# Laravel routes with domains and subdomains

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, subdomain

I've an app developed with laravel 5 and I will deploy it in a digitalocean droplet.

- Can I have multiple domains and subdmanins in my server that using this unique application?
- How I should implement routes.php to involve that?

I use this code to subdomains on 'mysite.com'

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.mysite.com'), function() {
    Route::get('customer/{customerId}', function() {
        //blablabla;
    });
});
```

But What I have to do if I have others domains like 'othersite.com'?

PS: All domains are hosted in the same droplet.

Answer (score 0):

For subdomain, no problem (like said in http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing)

For domain, you can, but with the url set in the config you'll have problem with link...

So, i'll do things like that :

Get the domaine name ( something like $request->server->get('SERVER_NAME') or request()->server->get('SERVER_NAME') )

update the config with \Config::set('app.url', $mydomainename)

You can do that in route, but maybe it will be better in a middleware.

And voila

Ps: take care about duplicate content with google, maybe some canonical will be usefull